# How to automatically create support ticket via email

Tags: php, html, email, imap, pop3

I am designing a support ticket system in PHP and would like for support tickets to be automatically created when an email is sent to a specific email address.

For example, if someone emails support@mydomain.com, when the incoming mail arrives on the server, a support ticket is created (however I code that). Also, when someone replies to an email with an existing support ticket number in the subject, it will add that email reply to the existing ticket.

So, basically, I want my server to monitor any incoming messages to a specific email address. When messages arrive, take it and run it through a php page and I can break it down from there.

How is this done? I've seen it done many times with hosting companies, etc. You can respond via email and support tickets are automatically created.

Thank you!

Comment: Not really a question for StackOverflow though your best chance at working this out is to pick apart an opensource version of a ticket system that does this

Comment: Googleooogleooogleooogleoooglooogleooogle it!  the top links on G for read email in php or similar searches are php.net and this excellent class http://garrettstjohn.com/entry/reading-emails-with-php/ which you should easily be able to adapt to your needs.

Comment: Just to help some more, if you enter your IMAP credentials into garret's class, all you need is: $email=new email_reader();
$thismail =$email->get(1);
var_dump($thismail); to demonstrate the functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to set up an IMAP server and have your PHP script poll for new messages, then track them accordingly.  That's really the only, or at least, the most straightforward way.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently developing a plugin for a CMS which will enable you to contribute content by sending an email - and the approach is compareable.
Basically you need a dedicated mailbox (POP3 works as well - and don't get confused by naming: imap_ open can also access POP3- Mailboxes) and then:

```
Foreach (messages as msg) {
    If (Processing()) imap_delete(msg); // bool=success
 }
```

The implementation of "Processing" is left as an excercise to the reader ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use the mailgun api that does the heavy lifting for you.